# Index was out of range in RowStateChanged event , datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, indexing, datagridview

This is my code in RowStateChangedEvent

```
private void dataGridView1_RowStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewRowStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {




                if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Selected)
                {
                  //dosomething
                }




    }
```

And this is the form_load event(Where i fill datagridview)

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("c1", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("c2", typeof(string));

        dt.Rows.Add("somedata", "somedata");
        dt.Rows.Add("somedata", "somedata");

        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I get this error

[image]

Index was out of range.--- It returns -1 index in event , i dont know why.
Any ideas?

Comment: In which line do you get the error? `if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Selected)` ? And: Why not simply:  `if (e.Row.Selected)` ???

Comment: Also note that _This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values._ so you ought to test a state by `HasFlag()`

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if the index >= 0.  Some the events also fire for the header row which has a -1:

```
if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && dataGridView1.Rows[e.Row.Index].Selected)
{
    //dosomething
}
```